# How to create asp.net app combining ListBox, TextBox and Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I'm designing small instant messenger app on .NET platform.
I have a `ListBox`, `TextBox` and `Button` (called Send).

When user click `send button`, `Text of TextBox` will be appeared on `ListBox` but user should not send  `3 messages` in 1 minute(message restriction) and also his/her size of message should consist min 20 max 140 strings.

How can I do this?

Comment: kindly add proper tags in your question

Comment: if ((TextBox3.Text.Count() >= 20 && TextBox3.Text.Count() < 140))
           {
                   ListBox1.Items.Add("(" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + " " + "PM" + ")" + " " + TextBox6.Text + ":"+TextBox3.Text);
           }

Comment: I did size of message restriction but couldnt make message interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below uses the timer control, if you would like to learn more about using timers in ASP.NET have a look at [this](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/how-do-i-use-the-aspnet-ajax-timer-control) video tutorial by Joe Stagner.

Basically I'm storing the number of messages in ViewState and when that number reaches **3** I start the timer which will reset the `ViewState["Messages"]` back to 0 after 1 minute (60 000 milliseconds) and the user is once again able to send more messages.

**ASPX:**

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="Scriptmanager" runat="server" />
    <asp:Timer ID="timer" runat="server" Enabled="false" Interval="60000" OnTick="Tick" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox MaxLength="140" ID="txtMessage" runat="server" />&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="Send" />&nbsp; <span
                id="error" runat="server" style="color: Red;" />
            <br />
            <asp:ListBox ID="lbMessages" runat="server" Width="240" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        ViewState["Messages"] = 0;
}

public void Send(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    error.InnerHtml = string.Empty;
    string message = txtMessage.Text;

    if (message.Length < 20)
    {
        error.InnerHtml = "The message should be at least 20 characters long";
        return;
    }

    int messageNumber = (int)ViewState["Messages"];
    if (messageNumber < 3)
    {
        lbMessages.Items.Add(message);
        ViewState["Messages"] = ++messageNumber;

        if (messageNumber.Equals(3))
            timer.Enabled = true;
    }
}

protected void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["Messages"] = 0;
    timer.Enabled = false;
}
```

Also you don't need to check for maximum length in code, there is a property for that on the textbox - `MaxLength`

Comment: everything is OK,but when I write error.Html=string.Empty program gives en error "The name error does not exit in the current context" but ı defined as u shown above.How can I overcome this problem :(

Comment: You need to add `runat="server"` attribute to the tag to be able to access it from code behind.Just copy the span tag exactly as it is in my example

Comment: if (messageNumber.Equals(3))
   timer.Enabled = true;//here timer starting but I want to start to chat after 1 minute

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set an hidden field in your page load to store serialised three last requests time and another for last minute message count.

in the click button event get text of the textbox apply your size restriction and verify message count.

Comment: Thanks for second hint,I did textbox.tex.count() successfully, but I couldnt first one :(